# Bounding the derivative of a ration of two multivariable functions

Tags: limits, derivatives, lipschitz-functions

I am trying to bound the derivative of $$f(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{y})= \frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^3x_i(x_i+y_i)\right)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^3(x_i+y_i)^2},$$
over the box $-a\leq x_i,y_i\leq a$.

To that aim I tried to find the limit $\lim_{\boldsymbol{x}\rightarrow -\boldsymbol{y}}f(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{y})$, but I failed in calculating it. I tried to use LHopital rule to calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}f(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{y})$, but  it is unclear to me how to do it in multivariable function. Do I take the derivative according to $x_i$ in all the iterations or should I take the mixed derivatives?

Comment: The differential of $f$ cannot be bounded, since the derivative of $t\mapsto f((t,0,0),(1,0,0))=t^2$ is unbounded.

Comment: @AnneBauval Right. Let's say then that I'm interested in a bounded box $-a\leq x_i,y_i\leq a$. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By change of variable $\boldsymbol{z}=\boldsymbol{x}+\boldsymbol{y}$, this amount to bound (on some bounded subset of $\mathbb R^6$) the differential of
$$g(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{z})= \frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^3x_iz_i\right)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^3z_i^2}.$$
But
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial z_1}((1,1,0),(2t,t,0))=-\frac6{25t}$$
is not bounded when $t\to0.$

Comment: I am a bit confused by your result. The scenario you are describing is the same as setting $\boldsymbol{x}=(1,1,0)$ and $\boldsymbol{y}=(-1+2t,-1+t,0)$. Then the partials are $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}f= \frac{3}{2}(1+t)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y_1}f= \frac{3}{2}$, and the gradient is bounded when $t-> 0$. Isn't it so? Maybe there is some error due to the Jacobian in the transformation?

Comment: No, the "scenario" and the notation are not the same as in my first comment. Here, I first computed $\frac{\partial g}{\partial z_1}(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{z})$ and then I evaluated it at $\boldsymbol{x}=(1,1,0)$ and $\boldsymbol{z}=(2t,t,0)$.

Comment: I too first took the derivatives according to $x_1$ and $y_1$ and then set $\boldsymbol{x}=(1,1,0)$ and $\boldsymbol{y}=(1+2t,1+t,0)$. Why is this different? If the derivative is unbounded in the $XZ$ plane then there should be some translation to the $XY$ plane that captures is right? So what is it?

Comment: $\frac{\partial g}{\partial z_1}((1,1,0),(2t,t,0))=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_1}((1,1,0),(2t-1,t-1,0)),$ not $(2t+1,t+1,0).$